# Batch Script - Trim functionality and Removing blank lines

Tags: batch-file, automation

**Trim function :**

Is there a trim functionality in batch scripting ? i.e to remove trailing and begining spaces. Need to apply trim functionality to all the lines in a text file.
Below is the script that i have got so far. But this removes any first character, want it to remove only spaces, if any.

```
For /F "tokens=*" %%A in (Temp.txt) do (
    set line=%%A
    echo(!line:~1!>>Temp.txt
)
```

For example :
Input =

```
[Space][Space]This is just a example message[Space][Space]
[Space]This is second example message[Space][Space]
This is third example message[Space]
```

Output =

```
This is just a example message
This is second example message
This is third example message
```

[Space] is equal to 1 space character.

**Removing blank lines :**

In case there are lines present only with spaces/tabs and nothing else, how to remove them ?
Example :
Below is a line containing two spaces, then how to remove this entire line from a text file.

```
[SPACE][SPACE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an optimized pure batch solution that performs linearly with the number of lines, regardless how many characters must be trimmed. This solution is also symmetric in that it trims spaces and tabs from both the beginning and end of each line, and entirely removes any resulting lines that are empty. The script expects the file to be trimmed to be passed as an argument. For example `xtrim test.txt`, or `call xtrim "c:\test\test.txt"`. The result overwrites the original file.

**XTRIM.BAT**

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
>"%~1.new" (
  for /f "usebackq eol= tokens=*" %%A in ("%~1") do if "%%A" neq "" (
    set "ln=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    for %%k in (
      4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
    ) do for /f "eol= tokens=*" %%B in ("!ln:~-%%k!.") do (
      setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
      if "%%B" equ "." (
        endlocal
        set "ln=!ln:~0,-%%k!"
      ) else endlocal
    )
    echo !ln!
    endlocal
  )
)
move /y "%~1.new" "%~1" >nul
```

As with any pure batch script, the above cannot process lines that are greater than ~8191 bytes long, and it can become painfully slow if dealing with large files. However, this solution is about as fast as pure batch can get.

I have a much simpler and faster solution using [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a utility that performs regular expression find/replace on text files. JREPL.BAT is a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

The following one liner has the exact same functionality, except it effectively has no limits (~2 gigabytes per line max, in theory), and it is much faster when dealing with files of any appreciable size.

**JXTRIM.BAT**

```
@jrepl "^[ \t]*(.*?)[ \t]*$" "$1?$1:false" /jmatch /f %1 /o -
```

---

I believe both solutions above do what the OP desires. However, they do not do exactly what was asked. I trimmed both tabs and spaces, but the OP only asked to trim leading and trailing spaces. The OP only asked for tabs to be deleted when an entire line is deleted because it is empty or because it contains tabs and/or spaces.

The following modifications precisely meet the specification as laid out by the OP:

**XTRIM2.BAT**

```
    @echo off
    setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
    >"%~1.new" (
      for /f "usebackq tokens=* eol= delims= " %%A in ("%~1") do if "%%A" neq "" (
        set "ln=%%A"
        setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
        for %%k in (
          4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
        ) do for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%B in ("!ln:~-%%k!.") do (
          setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
          if "%%B" equ "." (
            endlocal
            set "ln=!ln:~0,-%%k!"
          ) else endlocal
        )
        for /f "eol= " %%B in ("!ln!") do echo !ln!
        endlocal
      )
    )
    move /y "%~1.new" "%~1" >nul
```

**JXTRIM2.BAT**

```
@jrepl "^[ ]*(.*[^ \t](.*[^ ])?)[ ]*$" "$1?$1:false" /jmatch /f %1 /o -
```

Comment: Works great! Can you explain the script a bit ?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

(for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   if "%%a" neq "" (
      set "line=%%a"
      setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
      call :rTrim
      echo !line!
      endlocal
   )
)) > output.txt
move /Y output.txt input.txt
goto :EOF

:rTrim
if "!line:~-1!" neq " " exit /B
set "line=!line:~0,-1!"
goto rTrim
```

Previous Batch file is based on these operative details:

- `FOR /F` command don't process empty lines, that is, it *removes* empty lines.
- `"TOKENS=*"` option remove leading spaces.
- When `DELIMS=` option is not given and a line contain just spaces and/or tabs, `%%a` is empty.

So the only complicated part is the right trim...

Comment: Pretty good, except it only right trims spaces, yet it left trims spaces and tabs. Also, it becomes ***very slow*** if there is a significant amount of right trimming to do.

Comment: Also, you have a bug in that a non blank line will be mistakenly stripped if the first non-space, non-tab character is a semicolon. You need to set EOL to a space. My first attempt had the same bug :-)

Comment: Doesnt `Exit /B` in the trim function end the whole script itself ? it looks as if it just ends the recursive trim and goes back to the for loop.

Comment: @Lastwish: :rTrim is invoked via a `call` command, so the `exit /B` executed inside it just ends it and return to the place where rTrim was called. BTW, rTrim is _not_ recursive: there is not any `call` command inside it...

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TrimSpace
    If LCase(Arg(1)) = "l" then 
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            Line=Inp.readline
            outp.writeline LTrim(Line)
        Loop
    ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "r" then
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            Line=Inp.readline
            outp.writeline RTrim(Line)
        Loop
    ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "lr" then
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            Line=Inp.readline
            outp.writeline Trim(Line)
        Loop
    ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "lc" then
        Count = Cint(LCase(Arg(2)))
'       msgbox count
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            Line=Inp.readline
'           msgbox Line & "  " & Len(Left(Line,Count)) & "  " & Len(Mid(Line, Count)) & "  " & Len(Space(Count)) & "  " & Len(Line)  
'           msgbox Left(Line,Count) & "End" & vbcrlf & Space(Count) & "End"
            If Left(Line,Count) = Space(Count) then
                outp.writeline Mid(Line, Count +1)
            Else
                outp.writeline LTrim(Line)
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

And

```
Sub BlankLine
    Set RegEx = New RegExp
    RegEx.Pattern = "^\s+$"
        If LCase(Arg(1)) = "e" then
            Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
                Line=Inp.ReadLine
                If Len(Line) <> 0 Then
                    OutP.WriteLine Line
                End If
            Loop
        ElseIf Lcase(Arg(1)) = "a" then
            Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
                Line=Inp.ReadLine
                If Len(Line) <> 0 Then
                    If RegEx.Test(Line) = False then
                        OutP.WriteLine Line
                    End If
                End If
            Loop
        End If
End Sub
```

Both scripts require the following 4 lines.

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
```

and you need to call the sub.

To use trim

```
cscript //nologo "path to script.vbs" "" l < "c:\inputfile" > "C:\outputfile"
```

and blanklines

```
cscript //nologo "path to script.vbs" "" a < "c:\inputfile" > "C:\outputfile"
```

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=E2F0CE17A268A4FA!121 is where you can download filter0.8.zip as a file easy to use. Filter has 19 text file functions and many options and is sample code for vbs processing of text files. Showing how easy it is. All individual functions are in one sub.